# How to create Custom Authentication Attribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

How to create Custom Authentication Attribute in C# Web API

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace WebApiCustomAuthorization
{
    public class MyAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool Authorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
             return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace WebApiCustomAuthorization
{
    public class MyAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
             return actionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("m=1") || base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for custom authorize attribute.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any() ||
            actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any())
            return;
        if (!actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        /// additional condition 
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
}
```